# Slow SQL queries

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, performance

I'm having some issues with my webpage.

It was running really slow, so I read on the Internet that it might be a bad usage of SQL. So I commented the SQL lines that were more 'complex' and it started running smoothly again.

My question is: 'Is there a way to make this SQL request "lighter"?

```
    @companies = Company.where('tbl_companys.state = "enabled"')

    @companies = @companies.includes(:benefit).where("tbl_benefits.end_date >= {Date.today}" )

    @companies = @companies.includes(:benefit).where(tbl_benefits: { state: 'enabled' })

    has_benef_gastro = false

    has_benef_hote = false

    has_benef_ent = false

     until has_benef_gastro == true

        @esta_gastro = (@companies.where('id_category = "2-gastronomia"').shuffle)[0]

        @benefit_gastro = Benefit.where('id_company = ? AND end_date >= ? AND state = "enabled"', @esta_gastro.id_company, Date.today).first 

        if @benefit_gastro.nil? == false

            has_benef_gastro = true

        end

    end

    until has_benef_hote == true

        @esta_hotelero = (@companies.where('id_category = "1-hoteleria"').shuffle)[0]

        @benefit_hote = Benefit.where('id_company = ? AND end_date >= ? AND state = "enabled"', @esta_hotelero.id_company, Date.today).first 

        if @benefit_hote.nil? == false

            has_benef_gastro = true

        end

    end

    until has_benef_ent == true

        @esta_ent = (@companies.where('id_category = "3-entretenimiento"').shuffle)[0]

        @benefit_ent = Benefit.where('id_company = ? AND end_date >= ? AND state = "enabled"', @esta_ent.id_company, Date.today).first 

        if @benefit_ent.nil? == false

            has_benef_gastro = true

        end

    end
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: The first thing to do is to output timediffs between each line to see where the time is going. If you end up wanting to tune SQL, you'll need to provide table definitions, volumes and indexes.

Comment: The use of shuffle concerns me. Basically it look to me like you're getting a random company, checking to see if that works, if not repeat.  Is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing a plain SQL request so I didn't had to struggle with some rails issues.

Thanks anyway !

Answer (score 0):

You're shuffling the `@esta_gastro`, `@esta_hotelero`, `@esta_ent`, and the `@benefit_` variables every time, which doesn't really make sense.  It requires multiple new DB queries every single time you do a loop.

If you want to find a random selection, just create your sets outside of the loop, shuffle once (outside of the loop), and then iterate over those sets until you meet your criteria.

For example:

```
@esta_gastro = @companies.where('id_category = "2-gastronomia"').shuffle
@benefits = Benefit.where('end_date >= ? AND state = "enabled"', Date.today)
@benefit_gastro = nil
i = 0
until !@benefit_gastro.blank?
  @benefit_gastro = @benefits.where('id_company = ?', @esta_gastro[i].id_company).first
  i += 1
end
```

**EDIT**

If the whole goal is to get the `@benefit_gastro` defined, then I don't even think you need a loop.  You could just define the `@esta_gastro` set and then use it find all the Benefits that correspond.  Because `@esta_gastro` is shuffled, your `@benefit_gastro` will be random:

```
@esta_gastro = @companies.where('id_category = "2-gastronomia"').shuffle
@benefit_gastro = Benefit.where('end_date >= ? AND state = "enabled"', Date.today).where('id_company = ?', @esta_gastro.map(&:id)).limit(1)
```